# How to properly write a query to use two copies of a single table?

Tags: sql, join

I need to show one attribute referring to two different instances of the same attribute.

I have a set of tables such as Branch, Address, Property_for_rent, State. I need to show properties data including the branch_state and the property_state. These two attributes come from the table state row name. My problem is that I haven't found a way to join the table state two times referring to two different instances. I already tried Full Join but sql doesn't recognize one copy of my table state, Union doesn't work because if I split the query into to I won't have the same amount of columns.

need to join this two queries:

```
SELECT p.property_no, p.prop_type, p.rooms, p.rent, s.name AS property_state, staff_no
FROM state s
JOIN address a ON s.state_id = a.state_id
JOIN property_for_rent p ON a.address_id = p.address_id
ORDER BY rent ASC;
```

---

```
+-------------+-----------+-------+------+----------------+----------+
| property_no | prop_type | rooms | rent | property_state | staff_no |
+-------------+-----------+-------+------+----------------+----------+
| PR200       | Flat      | 3     |   24 | Nevada         | SQ523    |
| PR901       | Flat      | 7     |   31 | Vermont        | SL569    |
| PR806       | House     | 3     |   54 | Minnesota      | NULL     |
```

---

```
SELECT branch_no, z.name AS branch_state
FROM branch b
JOIN address a ON b.address_id = a.address_id 
JOIN state z ON a.state_id = z.state_id;
```

---

```
+-----------+----------------+
| branch_no | branch_state   |
+-----------+----------------+
| B424      | Kentucky       |
| B947      | Massachusetts  |
| B942      | South Carolina |
| B714      | North Dakota   |
```

branch_state and property_state are alias for the name attribute in the state table.

Comment: What's the expected result in this case?

Comment: Please show the layout of the tables.  How is `branch` connected to the first query?

Comment: Yes I am working on it. It is my first time using stack overflow so I am figuring out how to add images. Thank you!

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. We cannot reason, communicate or search unless we make the effort to (re-re-re-)write clearly.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the branch to the property somehow.  Let me assume that `property_for_rent` has a column for `branch_id`:

```
SELECT p.property_no, p.prop_type, p.rooms, p.rent,
       sp.name AS property_state, staff_no,
       sb.name as branch_state
FROM property_for_rent p JOIN
     address ap
     ON ap.address_id = p.address_id JOIN
     state sp
     ON sp.state_id = ap.state_id JOIN
     branch b
     on p.branch_id = b.branch_id JOIN
     address ab
     ON ab.address_id = b.address_id JOIN
     state sb
     ON sb.state_id = ab.state_id
ORDER BY rent ASC;
```

Comment: Yes indeed. property_for_rent has a column branch_no which is primary key in the  branch table. Thank you. and sorry for the post a little unorganized.